# how this function is working. how change in bitmap object is happening

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, graphics, bitmap

why we are using graphics object here?

```
Bitmap bmpNew = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height,pixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
graphics.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(4 arg), new Rectangle(4 arg),   GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
graphics.Flush();
return bmpNew;
```

how this function (DrawImage) is changing the bitmap object please help?

Comment: You've really not provided a lot of information here. Knowing were source and graphics are declared would help.

Comment: You ask why the graphics object is being used, but you don't explain what the code does, what you *expect* it to do, and nor do you include the code that declares `graphics` or `source` so we're left to guess what that is (though to be honest, it's not hard to guess). The code uses `graphics` because *that's what it needs to use to work*; the real question is perhaps "what do you actually want to know?"

Comment: Sir i want to convert rgb image to gray scale 24 bit image. i am new in image processing. is it necessary to use graphics object and drawimage function?

Answer (score 0):

A bitmap and a screen are very similar, as the screen reads from an image buffer, which is in fact a bitmap. Thus, in some frameworks as e.g. WinForms which you seem to use, the same objects are used for drawing to a screen as drawing to a bitmap.

Thus, the function DrawImage draws the given image to the given bitmap, just like you would draw an image to the screen.